# How can I get user token from embed URL?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a community connector that takes data from my DB. But I want it to take data only for a specific user that will see a report on the website. How can I catch user token from ember URL? Or how I can filter this data in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the email address of the specific user? You can add their email address as a new column and use "row-level data security" released by Data Studio on February 13, 2020.

Users are required to sign in to the email address, and can only view the data that is relevant to them.

See the documentation here
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9713766

Comment: But this is only for @gmail.com users. Users on the website may have other email addresses. And how report will catch this email from embed link?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Community Connector, enforce viewer's credentials for your data sources. Then you will have access to the users's email address in Apps Script. Here's [the guide on this](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/row-level-filtering) using BigQuery Advanced Services.

Edit: If your users are not logged on to Google, use this guide on [Row level filtering with Embedded dashboards](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/viewers-cred-with-3p-credentials).

Comment: Hi, @Minhaz Kazi, this will only work if the user is logged in to google. I need this report to embed it to my website so all users according to there user_id can see it. I've found the article "Row-level filtering with Embedded dashboards", but my query not in the connector. It's on my server-side, and I really don't understand how to solve this.

Comment: Added a new link based on your updated requirement.